# Undefined control sequence when using `\includegraphics`

Tags: miktex, includegraphics

Can anyone suggest an idea why the code below reports an error?

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\Ginclude@graphics ...\Ginput@path \set@curr@file 

                                                  {#1}\edef \uq@curr@file {\...

l.7 \includegraphics{HR.jpg}
```

I'm using MiKTeX 2.9 on Windows 10 and it fails with all LaTeX'es except LuaLateX.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\includegraphics{HR.jpg}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/511749/miktex-graphics-bug-persists-for-miktex.

Comment: Using recent 64-bit MikTeX I can compile your MWE with some my `.png` image without any problem.

Comment: That is what I expected. I just wonder if anyone has ever met such kind of a problem and possibly have a solution to it.

Comment: @sergeyg Probably you are running `LateX` instead of `PDFLaTeX` as you are using `.jpg` image...

Comment: The only difference I see is that LuaLatex uses LaTeX2e <2019-10-01>, while other failing latex'es are using LaTeX2e <2018-12-01>.

Comment: Yes, it is duplicate as stated above. Thank you for helping me!